# How is there tension difference in a rope if we assume external force is zero?

Tags: forces, waves, string, continuum-mechanics

Following from the hanging rope model [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/609822/), I understood that the tension only varies with length if the rope is accelerated by external forces. Now, I was reading the  proof of wave equation [in this pdf](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/m267/wave.pdf), at end of end of the pdf, the common wave equation ( the one in most textbooks ) is resuled by setting $F_{ext} =0$ in this equation:

$$ \rho(x) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} u(x,t)= T(t) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(x,t) + F_{ext}(x,t)$$

Now if there are no external forces, then how come there is a tension gradient across the rope?

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): Why is $x$ not an argument to $T(t)$?

Comment: The author of pdf took the horizontal force balance  and from that condition derived it see inmiddle of  page 2 of linked pdf @Qmechanic